# Words for "a bit sad" and "a bit happy"?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Are there words or other phrases for "a bit sad" and "a bit happy"?

Thank you!

Edit:

I'm sorry for the confusion. I wanted at least two words: one for "a bit sad" and one for "a bit happy". Thanks anyway for the answers for mixed happy and mixed sad. I hope there will be other answers for the two distinct phrases. Thanks!

Comment: Look at the synonyms and antonyms: http://thesaurus.com/browse/sad - somber for a little sad for example

Comment: Do you want a word that means both at once, or words for each emotion separately?

Comment: @mplungjan thanks for "somber". I found "upset" and "cheerless" for "a bit sad". For "a bit happy", I think "contented" fits.

Comment: @starwed I want words for each emotion separately. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Bittersweet, maybe?

M-W:

> something that is bittersweet; especially :  pleasure alloyed with pain

Comment: Hey, sorry for the confusion. I wanted words for each emotion. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Conflicted could fit in this sense

according to Merriam-Webster's website:

> Conflicted:  experiencing or marked by ambivalence or a conflict especially of emotion

Comment: Hey, sorry for the confusion. I wanted words for each emotion. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

blitheness  showing a casual and cheerful indifference considered to be callous or improper.

or air·y giving an impression of being unconcerned or not serious, typically about something taken seriously by others.

joc·und cheerful and lighthearted.

vi·va·cious (especially of a woman) attractively lively and animated.

for sadness

de·spond·en·cy a state of low spirits caused by loss of hope or courage.

disheartenment cause (someone) to lose determination or confidence.

dispiritedness having lost enthusiasm and hope; disheartened.

downheartedness discouraged; in low spirits.

mel·an·chol·y a feeling of pensive sadness, typically with no obvious cause.

gloominess feeling distressed or pessimistic.

pes·si·mism a tendency to see the worst aspect of things or believe that the worst will happen; a lack of hope or confidence in the future.

also additional word 
tempestuousness characterized by strong and turbulent or conflicting emotion.

hope any of this helps~

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site Fran! Where did you find all of these definitions, and which one/s do you think fit the OP's question the best?