# Vocabulary word for something sweet yet sour at the same time.

Tags: expressions

Ok so I'm doing a Screen-write for a Romance-Comedy. It based of a "Sweet n' Sour" Relationship/Love.. But I need a Vocab word to title the story. Was thinking.... "Salted Love." but..... idk, I'm open for ideas.

Comment: I encourage you to review the different [types of tastes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taste)... there are five. Sweet and sour are each one of them... salty is a different one. "Salty" has zero implication of either sweet or sour, so I'm not sure how that's an option. Could you please explain yourself more completely?

Comment: I'm a Christian so don't mind if I quote a bible verse that says, "We are the Light of the word. Because we are the salt of the earth" <-- *WAY OFF* or... something like that. But in essence by comparing us to salt, Jesus meant. "SWEET/Taste" we are the sweet of the earth. But at times people dismiss using salt for something with the feedback that salt is too better their liking.. So yeah. "Salty Love" | Tasty <--> Yet, better....mmmm? :)

Comment: @TheInformantSpy In the "salt of the earth", salt is being exalted not for its flavor but because [at the time it was a medium of exchange](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/salt-of-the-earth.html), a kind of currency. Hence "worth his salt" and "salary". Salt was used as a preservative, so it was super important in days where food supplies waxed and waned with the seasons, and fridges were millennia from being invented. There really is no connotation of "a synthesis of two opposing flavors", anything about "sweet" or "sour" at all, or even "delicious".

Comment: Are you looking for a word that means "sad but also happy at the same time"?

Comment: @DanBron why then is salt without flavor said to be worthless?  "Ye are the salt of the earth: but if the salt have lost his savor, wherewith shall it be salted? it is thenceforth good for nothing, but to be cast out, and to be trodden under foot of men."

Comment: @phoog Fair point. I guess you can make the argument that the quote focuses on the "deliciousness" of salt (but still not that it is "sweet" or "a combination of sweet and sour"). Having said that, historically, the value of salt as a medium of exchange was definitely based on its use as a preservative. The link I offered makes the argument that this is the real reason the analogy spoke to the congregation.

Comment: @Laurel yes I'm looking for a word that means sad but also happy. Sweet yet sour. Like the sweet n' sour candy commercial ;)

Comment: bittersweet? [Link: Thesuarus.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/bittersweet) I hope that helped.

Comment: This question is really a duplicate of this one then: http://english.stackexchange.com/q/137639/191178

Answer (score 1):

***Tangy***

From [www.thefreedictionary.com/](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/)tangy

*A distinctively sharp taste, flavor, or odor, as that of orange juice. 2. A distinctive quality*

[www.urbandictionary.com](http://www.urbandictionary.com) defines term 'tangy'

*A sweet flavor that also gives something a little "kachow"! Tangy can be referred to as sweet yet spicy.*

Hard to pin down, really.  But the word might work for you.